# asp.net core 3.1 antiforgery on docker - exceptiiion deserializing token

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

when i run my app on linux everything is fine, 
but when i run it on docker i have following stack:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery[7]
      An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
 ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {9f0347d0-eb7f-4e10-9b16-17c276c69737} was not found in the key ring.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext httpContext)
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware[7]
      Error unprotecting the session cookie.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {6209e3db-9865-4b93-96a2-8e0ea0f50d3a} was not found in the key ring.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.CookieProtection.Unprotect(IDataProtector protector, String protectedText, ILogger logger)
```

and then after some 30 seconds

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HLUJ4NPUIB4L", Request id "0HLUJ4NPUIB4L:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at RandevouApiCommunication.ApiQuery.PostSpecific[TResult,TQueryDto](String address, TQueryDto dto, AuthenticationHeaderValue auth)
   at RandevouApiCommunication.Authentication.AuthenticationQuery.GetLoginAuthKey(String username, String password)
   at RandevouMVC.Models.ApiQueryProvider.ApiQueryProvider.Login(String username, String password) in /app/RandevouMVC/Models/ApiQueryProvider/ApiQueryProvider.cs:line 34
   at RandevouMVC.Models.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(String username, String password) in /app/RandevouMVC/Models/Authentication/AuthenticationManager.cs:line 18
   at RandevouMVC.Controllers.AuthenticationController.Login(UserLoginViewModel vm) in /app/RandevouMVC/Controllers/AuthenticationController.cs:line 47
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

i have looked over solutions but nothing helps...

my program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel(options=>{
                    options.ListenAnyIP(4444);
                });
    }
```

my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;

            });
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(opts =>
            {
                opts.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
            //services.AddDataProtection().DisableAutomaticKeyGeneration();

            BusinessServices.Register(services);

            services.AddMvc(config=>{
                config.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
        }
    }
```

and finally my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
#RUN cp /build/RandevouApiCommunication.dll ./RandevouMVC/
COPY ./*sln ./
COPY ./RandevouMVC/*.csproj ./RandevouMVC/

RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .


EXPOSE 4444
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RandevouMVC.dll"]
```

the problem fire when i send a post :"

```
namespace RandevouMVC.Controllers
{
        [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]
    public class AuthenticationController : PrimaryController
    {
        private readonly IAuthenticationManager _authManager;
        public AuthenticationController(IAuthenticationManager authManager)
        {
            _authManager = authManager;
        }

     [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(ControllerActionResult result = null)
        {
            if (result?.Message != null)
                ViewBag.OperationResult = result.Message;

            var vm = new UserLoginViewModel
            {
                Login = string.Empty,
                Password = string.Empty,
                ApiKey = _ApiKey,
            };

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_ApiKey))
            { 
                vm.LoggedUser  = _authManager.GetLoggedUser(_ApiKey)?.Name;
            }

            return View(vm);
        }

     [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(UserLoginViewModel vm)
        {
            string apiKey = _authManager.Login(vm.Login, vm.Password);
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(apiKey))
            {
                var result = new ControllerActionResult { Message = "Nie udało się zalogować" };
                return RedirectToAction("Index", result);
            }

            else
            {
                var result = new ControllerActionResult { Message = apiKey };
                return RedirectToAction("Index", result);
                // HttpContext.Session.SetString("ApiKey", apiKey);
                // vm.LoggedUser = _authManager.GetLoggedUser(_ApiKey)?.Name;
                // HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", vm.LoggedUser);
                // return View("Index", vm);
            }
        }
}
```

what is more, if i don't call

```
_authManager.Login(vm.Login, vm.Password);
```

(it only sends post to api on localhost)
it works...

i don't need any antiforgery, i only use session to keep apiKey  (received after logging in) on it, then i send it every request in headers

even if do sth like this in login method:

```
try{
            apiKey = _authManager.Login(vm.Login, vm.Password);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                 var errresult = new ControllerActionResult { Message = ex.Message };
                return RedirectToAction("Index", errresult);
            }
```

i have to wait ~ 30 seconds and then i get same errors, and the Exception.Message is:

```
One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)
```

can sb help me :) ?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: yeah of course, im not sure what fixed the problem, it was long time ago, but i think: i did somethig like 
            services.AddMvc(config => config.EnableEndpointRouting = false;)